# HTML: Place table right aligned in other table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a `table` inside of a `td` of another `table` to be aligned at the right side.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      <table style="width: 200px; table-layout: fixed; background-color:blue">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input style="width:100%" type="button" value="OK" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input style="width:100%" type="button" value="Abbrechen" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the inner `table` is shown at the left side. How to accomplish?

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use them for tabular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-table;` to the inner table. Otherwise the `text-align` parameter won't apply, since it only applies to inline elements.

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      <table style="width: 200px; table-layout: fixed; background-color:blue; display: inline-table;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input style="width:100%" type="button" value="OK" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input style="width:100%" type="button" value="Abbrechen" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: YES, Thank you very much!